# Error when running Appium on SauceLabs --> posix spawn failure, code 253

Tags: ios, appium, saucelabs

I am attempting to run my tests suit on SauceLabs cloud (using Appium) for a trial and I am repeatedly getting the following message in the log:

[33m[INST STDERR] posix spawn failure; aborting launch (binary == /var/folders/bl/1800rz_j7blcqx8pthyrq59h0000gn/T/tmpb4mJhr/myApp.app/myApp).[39m
2015-03-29 14:02:07:379 -

info: [debug] [33m[INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Error Starting Recording[39m
2015-03-29 14:02:07:444 -

info: [debug] [90m[INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253[39m

I think it has something to do with the way our app is compiled but the test works flawlessly on my local Mac and on my device as well (compiled for Debug).
I tried the same with their sample app and it works just fine. Is there something I am missing? 
Thanks in advance, Pavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running on saucelabs you're probably in the iPhone simulator, which runs on x86_64 architecture. Its likely you're sending it an app compiled to run on ARM (what real iDevices use), which the simulator doesn't understand.

If you're using the `xcodebuild` command to build your app from the terminal, you can add the flag `-sdk iphonesimulator8.1` or similar. It will handle the rest, and you should be able to run that on saucelabs.

Comment: Interesting... Can I see in the logs wether I run on x86 or on ARM when I reach SauceLabs? I'll check your advice in the office tomorrow..
Thanks!

Comment: This indeed helped me! Thanks a lot Nick!